Can I use "one" and "they/them/their" in the same sentence?


One must take care of their dependents.
One should always find a job they love.


Are the above sentences unnatural because I use "one" and "their/they" in the same sentence? I asked two different native speakers and their opinions are divided, so I don't know what I should do. Thank you in advance!

They are unnatural. If you start with 'one', conclude with 'one'. 1. One must take care of one's dependents. 2. One should always find a job one loves. Note that using 'one' in conversation may be seen as old-fashioned or excessively formal.

It's not uncommon to mix pronouns like this, so don't be surprised if you see it. (Googling gives examples like "One should avoid sleeping on their front", "Rastas believe one should not cut their hair", "One should vary their vegetables and fruits to obtain a wide range of nutrients", etc - possibly because one's sounds very formal, even moreso than one.) But it should be avoided if possible, especially if you're being assessed on your English knowledge.

@StuartF: I think it's only "not uncommon" (in speech) to violate the rule about not switching pronouns for the same referent mid-sentence when the first pronoun is one. And that's only because many people rarely use one as a generic pronoun anyway, so they're already uncomfortable and want to be rid of it if they got suckered into using it even once. It's not quite so awful as She should chew their food, but One should chew their food sounds pretty bad to me. Learners should definitely avoid it.

"Their" is perfectly OK with "everyone", "someone", and "no one", so maybe that's an influence on switching from "one" to "their". There's another question on the same topic here, but I think I prefer the answer below.

@MichaelHarvey I'd say the examples being asked about sound more natural to me (as a native AmE speaker) than yours, even if they're "technically" less correct. Using "one [...] their" sounds less archaic and stilted than "one [...] one's".

@Hearth - well, whatever floats your (one's) boat, but I find One should always find a job they love sounds (and looks) madly, crazily, wrong. The abrupt jolt between pronouns. One man's 'stilted' is another man's 'correct'.

Pronouns must always match and there's no get-out clause for 'one' and 'their'.
The details belong to a lengthy discussion with your IELTS teacher and for now, please note, using 'one' normally gives that pronoun much more significance than any of the others.
In idiomatic speech using the pronoun 'one' is half-way to using the Royal 'we'
While in strict grammar, there's nothing special about either, in real life both are elevated above the other pronouns.

Devoid of context, both your sentences are clear enough that few would misunderstand them, even if their ambiguity makes them inelegant (and arguably wrong). But you should be aware that context could make them unambiguously mean something else. For example, if you say, “It’s important to make one’s parents proud, and one should always find a job they love”, then they will almost universally be understood to refer to the parent, not to one.


One must take care of one's dependents.
(i) You should take care of your dependents.
(ii) They should take care of their dependents
One should always find a job one loves.
(i) You should always find a job you love.

One of the reasons for using the impersonal pronoun one is the desire to sound formal.  In my opinion, using the same pronoun repeatedly can be overkill as seen in this example below:

(a) The more one knows the dizzier one gets. The more one knows about a subject the more one knows how much one does not know and how, quite possibly, and even justly, one could fail.
Trust in an Age of Arrogance By C. Fitzsimons Allison

This excerpt uses the possessive form:

(b) And as far as experts in the area, you would have difficulty getting experts to claim they're experts; because the more one knows about a subject, the more one recognizes the bounds of one's knowledge.

In formal writing, especially in an English exam, there is a simple rule; do not mix different pronouns if the subject does not change in the sentence.



subject pronoun
possessive determiner
reflexive




I
my
myself


you
your
yourself


he
his
himself


she
her
herself


it
its
itself


one
one's
oneself


we
our
ourselves


you
your
yourselves


they
their
themselves




I would add, it's worth sticking to the rule not just because it's a rule, but because switching pronouns can create confusion. The OP's examples are straightforward enough, but sometimes switching pronouns could leave us looking for an unidentified antecedent.

Does "one" and "one's" in the same sentence sound awkward to native speakers, due to the repeated sound?

@AnIELTSLearner  It will sound "posh" to some. Other speakers won't bat an eyelid.
